# JQuery triggering custom event causes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, eventemitter

I have a person object and I essentially want it to be able to emit its own events.
However if the trigger event has the same name as the prototype than Chrome prints out a rather large error.  In the code sample below  `person.murder` triggers the `murder` event which writes an error to console. (the code makes more sense).

```
function Person() {

}

Person.prototype.murder = function() {
   $(this).trigger("murder");
}
```

And I invoke the trigger like this

```
var barry = new Person();
$(barry).on("murder", function(){
   alert("I am so angry");
})

barry.murder();
```

So murdering barry causes an error,  however if the event was something like `personDied` than there is no error.   Am I triggering the event correctly?  I just want to murder people without error.

The error is sometimes returned as a collapsed `<error>` and sometimes as

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: +1 for "I just want to murder people without error."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery is calling the method recursively. From http://api.jquery.com/trigger/:

```
Note: For both plain objects and DOM objects, if a triggered event name matches the name
of a property on the object, jQuery will attempt to invoke the property as a method if no
event handler calls event.preventDefault(). If this behavior is not desired, use
.triggerHandler() instead.
```

So you should use `triggerHandler` instead of `trigger`.

Comment: Thats interesting!  I guessed the recursive thing from the error but had no idea it was by design!  triggerHandler works a treat.  Nice one

Answer (score 1):

The trigger `murder` calls the method `murder` on `Person` since you trigger it on the object `Person`. That will again call the `murder` method and so on (unending loop).

If you use jQuery's `.triggerHandler()` function it will only trigger the trigger, and not call the method.

```
function Person() {

}

Person.prototype.murder = function() {
   $(this).triggerHandler("murder");
}

var barry = new Person();
$(barry).on("murder", function(){
   alert("I am so angry");
})

barry.murder();
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6neHC/

jQuery `.triggerHandler()` doc:

http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/